# matching doublequotes in PHP regex

Tags: php, regex, double-quotes

I'm trying to write what should be a fairly simple regex for a PHP script to match `tag:` followed by a word in double quotes. I want it to return just the value inside the quotes, minus the quotes themselves (`tag:"whatever"` returns `whatever`).

I have a search box on a page which submits the form data (via GET, if that matters) to itself, and runs a PHP script on it. This is what happens inside the script:

```
$q = urldecode(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'q', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
preg_match_all("/tag:\"([\w]+)\"/", $q, $tags);
```

I want it to match something like `tag:"this"`, but when I search for that, I get no matches:

```
//print_r($tags) yields:
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
    )
  [1] => Array
    (
    )
)
```

I figured it might be an escaping issue, so I also tried

```
$q = stripslashes(urldecode(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'q', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)));
preg_match_all("/tag:\"([\w]+)\"/", $q, $tags);
```

and

```
$q = urldecode(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'q', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
preg_match_all("/tag:\\\"([\w]+)\\\"/", $q, $tags);
```

Both of these return the same array of two empty arrays.

In desperation I even tried it with single quotes (and searching for `tag:'this'`), which I didn't need to escape, but this also returned nothing:

```
$q = urldecode(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'q', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
preg_match_all("/tag:'([\w]+)'/", $q, $tags);
```

Removing the quotes, incidentally, makes it work fine:

```
//searching for tag:something with preg_match_all("/tag:([\w]+)/", $q, $tags); yields:
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [0] => tag:something
    )
  [1] => Array
    (
      [0] => something
    )
)
```

I'm almost certain I'm making a really foolish mistake, but stare at it as I might, I can't figure out what. I have tried searching for it, but was unable to find anyone with the same problem. This further leads me to think the problem is trivial, and that I'm being dim. Help!

Comment: Try `var_dump($q);` so you can see exactly what `$q` is.

Comment: Switch your outer quotes to single, which will eliminate the need for all this escaping...  `'/tag:"([\w]+)"/'`  Quotes in a regex don't need to be escaped.

Comment: Can you do var_dump($q)? I am pretty sure that regexp works fine.

Comment: Hmm... you're right, Michael. For some reason I got it into my head that regexes needed to be doublequoted. Still not working, though :-(

Comment: var_dump($q) yielded `string(22) "tag:"whatever""`, which... means nothing to me.

Comment: okay, well I have tried several combinations from the answers and comments posted so far, and I am now convinced that the problem is not with the regex. I changed $q from a GET value to a hard-coded string and it matched properly. an escaping problem, then?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
preg_match('|tag:"(\w+)"|', $str, $results);
```

When using single quotes in PHP, it saves you the need to escape the double quotes, thus saving you the confusion over what to escape and what is a character in RegEx.